# Reference about $\sigma$-linked posets and related notions

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

In [this link](http://boolesrings.org/mpawliuk/2012/09/14/stevos-forcing-class-fall-2012-class-1/), the following list appears:

> **Some chain conditions** [of posets], listed from easiest to satisfy to hardest to
>   satisfy:
>
> - ccc
> - powerfully ccc
> - productively ccc
> - $\sigma$-finite-cc
> - $\sigma$-bounded-cc
> - $\sigma$-$2$-linked
> - $\sigma$-$n$-linked
> - $\sigma$-$n$-linked $\forall n$
> - $\sigma$-centered
> - countable

Is there some reference where these notions are defined and discussed, preferably with separating examples (i.e. showing a  poset which is $\sigma$-$n$-linked $\forall n$ but not $\sigma$-centered)?

Comment: Have you tried in the newer Kunen?If I recall correctly most of these notions are there (chap 3/4)

Comment: @CarloVonSchnitzel actually no, I'm using the older Kunen. I will check.

Comment: I believe we should have it in the library. The new Kunen.

Comment: Since I don't know how powerfully ccc and productively ccc are defined and read the new Kunen, they may not be defined there. (Obviously, there is always the chance that I simply forgot about them.)

Comment: @Stefan: A partial order is powerfully ccc if its finite powers are ccc, and productively ccc if its product with each ccc partial order is ccc.

Comment: See http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm141/fm14114.pdf

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you.

Comment: @CarloVonSchnitzel it seems that Kunen discusses only $\sigma$-linked and $\sigma$-centered, and not very systematically (more by the way...). One can however find there a separating example if one looks well (the amoeba order).

Comment: @hot_queen - thanks, that helps alot!